# Is it normal that Diablo 3 is very easy

Tags: diablo-iii

I started playing with a friend of mine and we got to somewhat level 20 and we started to up our difficulty from normal on up. (no idea what it's called exactly) After that we still noticed it was very easy and we went to the highest diffculty possible(Not the one you unlock at level 60) and it was still way too easy. We never die or get in danger. Is this normal in Diablo 3 or are we missing something? We're level 40 now. We played from level 30 - level 40 in the highest possible difficulty

Comment: Yes, Diablo 3 is very easy until you have hit 60 the first time and can crank it up to Torment. However, I advise against playing on Torment right away if you play hardcore. However, this is primarily opinion based since others might see it as difficult.

Comment: Playing at level 40 on Torment 6 is extremely difficult, actually. Normal difficulty (should be renamed to easy) is intended for newer players who are just getting used to the game.

Comment: No idea why this is flagged as opinion based. Probably people who only read the title. I'm saying: `We never die or get in danger` That's a fact. The question basically is, is Diablo 3 not meant to be challenging at first or are we missing something?

Comment: I agree, it's a fact that diablo 3 on normal difficulty is easy. You basically never die and just kind of go through the motions. To answer your question, Diablo 3 is meant to be easy on normal difficulty. You aren't missing anything. Just up the difficulty until you are satisfied with the playstyle.

Comment: @ChaseC Yeah well I have to reach level 60 first, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Loko If you play on NA servers and need help, let me know. I am Rhyinn #1349. http://us.battle.net/d3/en/profile/Rhyinn-1349/hero/11893854

Comment: Is this PC or Console?

Comment: @Virusboy PC :)

Comment: Yes thats normal, till you hit 65 then you go into expert.

Comment: To avoid close votes, perhaps reword your question to ask about the difficulty mechanics and how they impact gameplay for new characters or non lv60 characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a table of the difficulty and how it portrays to drops and monster health and exp.

This is how I usually play from scratch (new season and 0 paragon points).

- I start on Expert because early levels are so easy.
- I always start with bounties, I never play through the campaign. I recommend this because it's a great way to get rift shards quick and easy and you can use all of them once you get to level 70.
- If you have never played through the campaign and you are interested in it, it's fine to start with the campaign.
- Once I hit level 40ish, I usually have to turn the difficulty either up or down depending on my current items. If I've found a really good weapon, I turn it up. If I haven't found a good weapon, I turn it down to Hard.
- It's always a good idea to KILL MORE AT A LOWER DIFFICULTY than it is to TAKE LONGER AT A HIGHER ONE.
- Once you hit level 70, start rifting. Blood shards and rift guardians will be a great source to get legendaries.
- If you can skip Torment 1, do it. Torment 2 is a HUGE increase in legendary find and exp.

[image]

Comment: What does RORG on the Act 1 cache mean?

Comment: @troyen its the ring of royal grandeur. Its the best cache legendary that's only available from a1 caches. It reduces the set item needed for bonuses by 1

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is normal, after they updated the game they changed the difficulty settings, now you dont have to finish the game like 4 times to get to the hardest difficulty, instead you can adjust the difficulty to level up faster or at your own pace.

Comment: Can you enhance your answer a bit? Which update changed the difficulty? Difficulty can only be scaled down from in-game, going up requires starting a new game.

Answer (score -3):

It's easy if you don't mind dying. If your goal is to never die instead of rarely die, even the difficulties before torment (which you can only unlock at level 60/70) are challenging, as soon as you suddenly meet the wrong combination of elites and champions.

Any mobs other than elites and champions are just an elaborate scheme to boost Logitech stock by wearing out your left mouse button prematurely.

Comment: -1. Your goal isn't not dying, unless you are on hardcore. Also, as a Multishot DH, I can say that non-elite/champion mobs matter too.